# Match "MALE" but not "FEMALE" in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a string column with the following values

| Genders |
| --- |
| MALE; FEMALE; NON_BINARY |
| MALE |
| MALE; FEMALE |
| FEMALE |

I want to create two indicators: one if the `Genders` field contains the value `MALE` and another if it contains the value `FEMALE`.

Originally, I was just doing

```
,CASE WHEN genders LIKE '%MALE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gender_male
,CASE WHEN genders LIKE '%FEMALE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gender_female
```

but then I realized that `MALE` will always be present since it's a substring of `FEMALE`.

I then tried this

```
,CASE WHEN 'MALE' in UNNEST(split(genders, ";")) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gender_male
,CASE WHEN 'FEMALE' in UNNEST(split(genders, ";")) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gender_female
```

but this didn't work either.

I'm using BigQuery btw.

Comment: What is the indicator you want if the string contains, both, as in columns that contain `MALE; FEMALE`

Comment: Have you considered SELECT DISTINCT(STATE) FROM CUSTOMER;

Comment: @topsail in this case I don't need that. But if I do I'll probably just check in another subquery that both indicators are 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below instead

```
  ,CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(genders, r'\bMALE\b') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gender_male
  ,CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(genders, r'\bFEMALE\b') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gender_female
```

or

```
  ,IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(genders, r'\bMALE\b'), 1, 0) as gender_male
  ,IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(genders, r'\bFEMALE\b'), 1, 0) as gender_female
```

both with the output (if apply to sample data in your question)

[image]